# How to display success and error message in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to ask. How can I display success and error message in blade for my add/remove input field dynamically with Jquery in Laravel. All seems good because the data saved in database but the message for success message not appear. It only appear as a JSON. My second question, how can I make page refresh after the data has been submitted.

My Controller:

```
public function addtrainee(Request $request) 
{
  $data = [];
  $count =  $request ->input('counting');
  $x = 1;

  while($x<=$count){
    $this->validate($request, [
    'name'.$x => 'required',
    'category'.$x => 'required',
  ]);
  $x++;
  }
  
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $data);
  
  if ($validator->passes()) {

    $x=1;
    while($x<=$count){

    echo $request->input('name'.$x)."<br>";
    echo $request->input('category'.$x)."<br>";

    $trainees = new Trainee([
                'name' => $request->get('name'.$x),
                'category' => $request->get('category'.$x),
                ]);
                $trainees->save();

                $x++;
            }
            return response()->json(['success'=>'true']);
        }
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

My blade:

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
  {{csrf_field()}} 
  <div class="alert alert-danger show-error-message" style="display:none">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-success show-success-message" style="display:none">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="counting" class="form-control name_list" / id="counting" value="1">
  <div class="table-responsive">  
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field"> 
    <tr>  
       <td><input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list" / id="name"></td>  
       <td>
          <select  class="form-control category" id="category" name="category1">
             <option value="Male">Male</option>
             <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
       </td>
       <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
    </tr>  
   </table>  
   <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />  
  </div>
 </form>  

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){      
    var url = "{{ url('addtrainee') }}";
    var i=$("#counting").val();  
    
    $('#add').click(function(){  
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var category = $("#category").val();
        i++;  
        var counting = $("#counting").val(i);
        
        $('#dynamic_field').append(
            '<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added">'
            +'<td><input type="text" name="name'+i+'" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>'
            +'<td><select class="form-control category" name="category'+i+'"><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select></td>'
            +'<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
        });  

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){ 
        i--; 
        var counting = $("#counting").val(i);
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
    });  
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    
    $('#submit').click(function(){            
        
        $.ajax({  
            url:"{{ url('addtrainee') }}",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
            type:'json',
            success:function(data)  
        {
    
            if(data.error)
            {
                display_error_messages(data.error);
            }else
            {
                i=1;
                $('.dynamic-added').remove();
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                $(".show-success-message").find("ul").html('');
                $(".show-success-message").css('display','block');
                $(".show-error-message").css('display','none');
                $(".show-success-message").find("ul").append('<li>Trainees Has Been Successfully Inserted.</li>');
            }
         }  
        });  
    });  
    
    function display_error_messages(msg) {
        $(".show-error-message").find("ul").html('');
        $(".show-error-message").css('display','block');
        $(".show-success-message").css('display','none');
        $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
        $(".show-error-message").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
        });
        }
    });  
</script>
```

I have tried to change `return response()->json(['success'=>'true]);` to `return redirect('trainee')->with('success','Trainees Saved');` and add session error at my blade but it seems nothing happen.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What does `data` has in it ?

Comment: @Swati all input sir :)

Comment: Hi , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656611/my-validation-not-working-in-bootstrap-modal-using-ajax) might help .After making changes let me output of `data` .

Answer (score 0):

To make a response with an error, you need to specify the error code, e.g. 400

```php
return response(['error' => 'Message.'],400)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```